# using "packages" folder in DART

Tags: dart, dart-pub

In my app, I've the pubspec.yaml file as:

```yaml
name: server
dependencies:
   oracledart: any
```

and after running pub get, I got the folder "packages" updated correctly.

I wanted to create sub folders for testing my functions individually, so I created folder: test/boms.dart, which is:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:oracledart/oracledart.dart';

void main() {
  ...
}
```

but once running it, I got this error msg:

```
Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path =    'G:\app\bin\test\packages\oracledart\oracledart.dart' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Do I need to copy the 'packages' folder to each sub folder have the function "main", or there is another way to connect it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the DART team, should make symlinks auto generation in sub folders of the "bin" folder, same as the case of the sub folders of the "web" folder.

anyhow, to create them manually in Windows 7, I found it make as below:

```
1. run CMD as admin
2. mklink /D myApp\bin\test\packages myApp\packages   [D for directory, not drive]
```

I found how to make symlinks in windows [here](http://www.windows7home.net/how-to-create-symbolic-link-in-windows-7/)

another full detailed way is mentioned [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)

Comment: Why do you have the `test` directory below `bin`? This should be `your_package/test/your_test.dart`. Where does `\Packages` point to?. `Packages` should be lowercase and it should point to the `packages` directory in your package root not your drive root. I have no windows to test it but the command arguments don't look right.

Comment: I created a bugreport for this a while ago but it got closed for IMHO an invalid reason https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16947

Answer (score 1):

At least for top-level folders the `packages` link should be created automatically. Try run `pub get` or `pub upgrade` or create the `test` folder from within DartEditor (I don't know what creates the symlinks but usually they are created automatically in top-level folders as far as I remember). In subfolders of top-level folders like `bin`, `test`, ... I always had to create them manually by creating a new symlink to the `packages` link in the package root.

In Linux like:

```bash
ln -s ../packages/ packages
```

don't know how to in Windows.

Comment: thanks @Gunter, the symlinks  are created automatically in both top level and sub folders of the "web" folder, but not for the sub folders of the "bin" folder